# Is it 'look what happened' or 'look at what happened'?

Tags: phrases

Suppose Alan said something ridiculous, and then Betty says,

> That's what my father said. And **look what happened to him**.

Should the sentence in bold be changed to this?

> And look at what happened to him.

Not sure whether it is 'look what happened' or 'look at what happened'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence is correct as it is. Your version means the same thing.

Here's the same structure in an example sentence from [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/look):

> **2 :** to ascertain by the use of one's eyes
> // *look what I brought you*